# mysqldump, avoid escape double quotes

Tags: mysql, escaping, special-characters

When I have a field with double quotes, mysqldump put the escape character before. For example:

'My "test"' -> mysqldump generates a file with that field like 'My \"test\"'

The problem is that I'm using that file to import some data into a sqlite database, and SQLite doesn't remove the escape character. So I don't need that mysqldump writes escape characters, can I do that?

Comment: If you could provide code that you have tried that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If on a *nix (unix, linux, mac) machine, I can suggest using sed to replace \" with ":

```
mysqldump [options] DB [table] | sed -e 's/\\"/"/g'
```

or, for an exsiting `mydump.sql` file:

```
sed -i -e 's/\\"/"/g' mydump.sql
```

**EDIT:** searching for a formal MySQL answer , I only found this somewhat related open bug about single quote escaping - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65941

It's also worth mentioning that there are other tools that can dump DBs without escaping quotes with backslash in the first place, such as JetBrains products (`DataGrip`, `IntelliJ` etc).

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what language you are using. 
But the concept would be the same in any programming language.

First declare a variable equal to your sqldump.

```
var yourVariable = sqldump;
```

Then do a string.replace("\\", "").
Then use that 'cleaned' version to import your data with.

Answer (score -1):

From a google search I found [this](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776) which is reworking the output of mysqldump so sqlite can use it.
Not tested and 5 years old but I think:

- you may find useful information
- it may mean other people didn't find a more elegant solution

**EDIT:**

As per the comments, to answer your question it looks like you don't have a choice but replace `\"` into `"`.

[Here](https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite) is a repo with a [script](https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite/blob/master/mysql2sqlite.sh) which translates mysqldump files into something sqlite can digest.
In particular, for your question, you can find [this line](https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite/blob/master/mysql2sqlite.sh#L55):

```
gsub( /\\"/, "\"" )
```

Answer (score -1):

Which SQL mode do you use?
Look at the mysqldump manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

> --quote-names, -Q
>
> Quote identifiers (such as database, table, and column names) within
>   “`” characters. If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, identifiers
>   are quoted within “"” characters. This option is enabled by default.
>   It can be disabled with --skip-quote-names, but this option should be
>   given after any option such as --compatible that may enable
>   --quote-names.

`--quote-names` is enabled by default.

> ANSI_QUOTES
>
> Treat “"” as an identifier quote character (like the “`” quote
>   character) and not as a string quote character. You can still use “`”
>   to quote identifiers with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled,
>   you cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings,
>   because it is interpreted as an identifier.

Comment: The issue is within the data, not the table and column names

Comment: This misunderstands the question, which is about how literal `"` marks in the data are represented in the dump.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert escapes in the mysqldump output file.
Check [esperlu MySQL to Sqlite converter script](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776):

```
...
/INSERT/ {
    gsub( /\\\047/, "\047\047" )
    gsub(/\\n/, "\n")
    gsub(/\\r/, "\r")
    gsub(/\\"/, "\"")
    gsub(/\\\\/, "\\")
    gsub(/\\\032/, "\032")
    print
    next
}
...
```